# Name of a function return type as name of user define data type

Tags: c, enums, user-defined-types

Is it legal to name a function same as that of a user defined data type with enum ,in C? 
For Example:

```
enum sentence_id sentence_id(const char *sentence, bool strict);
```

and enum sentence_id is defined as given below

```
enum sentence_id {
MINMEA_INVALID = -1,
MINMEA_UNKNOWN = 0,
MINMEA_SENTENCE_RMC,
MINMEA_SENTENCE_GGA,
MINMEA_SENTENCE_GSA,

};
```

Is it applicable to other user defined data type(as structure)?

Comment: Please choose one language.

Comment: It is a function returning the defined type. Both the type and the function have been named identically. It works in C but it is a bad idea to duplicate identifiers.

Comment: There is no expectation if you'd understand it since it is simply invalid C# code. Please clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: `[return type] [function name]([args list])`, applied to your code, function `minmea_sentence_id` will return an `enum minmea_sentence_id` value. It's bad practice to use the same identifiers twice, but it's possible. Read this as if it said `enum minmea_sentence_id my_function(...)`, and know that if you assign the return value, that variable should be declared as `enum minmea_sentence_id my_var;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only looks strange, because the identifier for the enumeration and the function are identical, which is possible, because a enumeration identifier always has to follow an `enum` keyword and an `enum` always is followed by an identifier.

So let's give them different names:

```
enum minmea_sentence_id_e 
{
…
};
```

This defines an enumeration with the name `minmea_sentence_id_e`.

The function gets another identifier, too:

```
enum minmea_sentence_id_e minmea_sentence_id_f(const char *sentence, bool strict);
```

Now it should be quite clear that there is a function called `minmea_sentence_id_f` returning a value of enumeration named `minmea_sentence_id_e`.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand the meaning of this statement

So I assume this is not your code. Let's see what the other person wrote:

> ```
> enum minmea_sentence_id { ... };
> ```

In (Objective-)C this declares an enumeration type, `minmea_sentence_id` which is used by prefixing the name with `enum`. So for example:

```
enum minmea_sentence_id mySentenceID;
```

declares a variable of type `enum minmea_sentence_id` named `mySentenceID`.

Note that if instead of the above they had written:

```
typedef enum { ... } minmea_sentence_id;
```

then `minmea_sentence_id` would be a type name by itself and the above example declaration would just have been:

```
minmea_sentence_id mySentenceID;
```

However they didn't do that, so you need the `enum` when using the type.

> why is it repeated twice?

They wrote the function declaration:

> enum minmea_sentence_id minmea_sentence_id(const char *sentence, bool strict);

The first item in a function declaration is the return type, and from the above we know that is the first two tokens `enum minmea_sentence_id`.

Next comes the name of the function being declared, `minmea_sentence_id`, which looks strange – naming a function the same as a type – but is not illegal at all, though usually strongly discouraged as it makes code much harder to read!

So that's why it is repeated twice, but why might they have done this?

We can only guess, but (Objective-)C++ supports *function-style casts*, e.g.:

```
int x = (int)expo; // valid in (Objective-)C(++)
int y = int(expr); // valid in (Objective-)C++ and NOT in (Objective-)C
```

Now consider what a call to the `minmea_sentence_id` function looks like:

```
enum minmea_sentence_id mySentenceID = minmea_sentence_id("my sentence", TRUE);
```

a bit like a function-style cast. So maybe that is what they were thinking, but it's only a guess!

HTH

Comment: It's clear now.. Thank You :-)